# GCC : Static array index in function argument doesn't trigger any warning

Tags: c, gcc, clang, gcc-warning

I'm trying to understand the use of the "static" keyword as an array index in a function declaration in C.

After reading [this article](https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2013-02-18-static-array-indices.html), I tried to declare such a function, and purposefully passing it an array that is too short:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void print_string10(char string10[static 10]) {

// Should trigger a warning if the argument is NULL or an array of less than 10 elements

    printf("%s\n",string10);

}

int main(void) {

    char short_string[] = "test";

    print_string10(short_string); // should trigger a warning as the string is 5 long

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiling with `clang` as in the article triggers the warning, but `gcc -Wall -Werror` does not, it compiles and run fine.

I couldn't find an explanation, is that a normal behaviour for GCC to omit this warning?

Comment: Which versoin of GCC do you have? Do you pass any other options or flags when building?

Comment: It seems that none of the messages are required. The compiler can just ignore the keyword there.

Comment: I'm using gcc 6.3.0, with only `-Wall -Werror`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in GCC.  It seems there were some disagreements regarding whether or not this should be reported at compile time.  Nonetheless, it was accepted as a bug but there doesn't seem to be a priority on fixing it.

This is detailed in bug report [50584](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50584).  Comment 9 in particular states:

> (In reply to Malcolm Inglis from comment #4)
>
> > Could someone change the status of this bug?
>
> Notwithstanding whether the feature is pretty or ugly, GCC does accept
>   this code and warnings for undefined behavior, when possible, are
>   desired. Thus, confirmed.
>
> This does not mean anyone is going to work on fixing this. Please, if
>   you are using this feature and would like to see this warning in GCC,
>   please consider contributing it:
>   https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Basics:_Contributing_to_GCC_in_10_easy_steps
>
> If you start working on this, it would be good to say so here.

Comment: We should note it is a bug in that GCC does not conform to the behavior desired by its maintainers/contributors/supplicants, not that it is a bug in that GCC does not conform to the C standard.

Answer (score 6):

**Why** it does not **need** to trigger a warning is because of the section of the standard where it occurs - [6.7.6.3p7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7):

> **Semantics**
>
> [...]
>
> 7. A declaration of a parameter as ''array of type'' shall be adjusted to ''qualified pointer to type'', where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument **shall** provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

It appears in the *semantics* section. A conforming implementation is only required to diagnose those that appear in the *constraints*. Even when it does not diagnose the violation here, it can use the knowledge of the `static` keyword to infer that the argument is not null, and that loop unrolling and other optimizations could expect an array that would have at least that many elements.

---

Do also note, that the [example 5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p21) there says that

```
   void   f(double      (* restrict a)[5]);
   void   f(double      a[restrict][5]);
   void   f(double      a[restrict 3][5]);
   void   f(double      a[restrict static 3][5]);
```

are all **compatible**, i.e. you can mix and match them in function pointer assignments without casts even though one has the `static` dimension!

It seems that clang (perhaps rightly so) loses its ability to diagnose anything if the call is realized through a function pointer:

```
void (*f)(double a[restrict static 3]);

int main(void) {
    double a[1] = {0};
    f(a);
}
```

(no diagnostics in Clang 7.0 - remove the `*` and you will get them).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In the link to the gcc bug tracker provided by dbush, someone states :

"I don't recommend this kind of usage of the static keyword.  There was even the possibility of removing/deprecating this feature.[...]"

Does anyone agree with this ? What should be used instead ?

Comment: @SuperBoby the [DR205](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_205.htm) complains about the *use* of the `static` keyword, not that the feature would be bad. It exists in 99, 11 and 17 revisions, it is not going away any time soon, so it should be supported by GCC *right now* to the fullest extent *instead* of only providing alternative mechanisms.

Comment: @SuperBoby furthermore the problem with the use of `static` is that it works *only* in function parameters, whereas some other mechanism might work everywhere where a pointer is needed

Comment: In what other case would you need to restrict an array size like this ?